# Determine the volume of an object from pictures

Tags: opencv

Im doing some preliminary research into the problem stated above. I have read a bit about OpenCV and it looks like it may be able to help me out.

I have a subject (it is a metal chain) i can take pictures of and would like to determine the volume of one of the chain links. I can take as many pictures as required. What would be required to accurately calculate the volume of the link? Would i need some size reference in the pictures?

What i am thinking to achieve my goal is to reconstruct a 3D model using x number of images, then import it into Solidworks/CAD to calculate length/width/volume etc.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you could apply [space carving](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.163.250) in this instance (PDF can be downloaded from the link).  This technique will allow you to construct a closed, polygonal representation of the subject.

And, yes, some means of establishing the scale of your object will be needed.  [Here](http://www.cse.unr.edu/~bebis/CS791E/Notes/CameraParameters.pdf) is a brief discussion of the camera intrinsic and extrinsic parameters that are used to establish a relationship between an image pixel and an area (or volume). Since space carving requires that the viewpoint change between each frame, it's probably a good idea to recompute the external camera calibration parameters (extrinsic parameters) frequently. OpenCV has some capacity for determining camera parameters, see [this reference](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html) or perhaps this [tutorial](http://dasl.mem.drexel.edu/~noahKuntz/openCVTut10.html).

Alteratively - if you can assume that the camera orientation will not change much between frames, you might try an easier method.  As you suggested, an object of known size and orientation may be placed in the image, thereby providing scale cues.  Note that this method is fairly straightforward, but will work under limited conditions.  Foreshortening due to perspective and changes in perceived scale due to changing camera orientation will limit this method.

Once the "space" of the chain has been identified and represented in polygonal (i.e. meshed) form, it should be straight-forward to compute the volume.  OpenCV provides some mathematical primitives that should help.

Comment: +1 thankyou for the info/links. Would a video sequence be easier to work with? What would be the difference between using HD video/SD video/HD pictures for the reconstruction?

Comment: A video sequence could be helpful, but there are some things to be considered.  Two adjacent video frames will probably not give you much to work with - the difference between them is not likely to be substantial.  The rate of image capture and the rate at which the camera is moved around the scene will determine differences between frames.  (Note that the camera may be moved or the object may be rotated within a still camera frame - they are more or less equivalent in this case).  OTOH, optical flow techniques could speed identification of features in adjacent frames (reference object, etc).

Comment: HD versus SD is an interesting question.  HD will give higher resolution, along with increased processing time. Many computer vision techniques begin with a filtering operation to attenuate unimportant signals (Gaussian blur, median filter, pyramidal downsampling, etc.). Thus, I try to start with the highest resolution image that makes sense in my constraints (time, memory, etc).  If this were my problem, I would prototype in SD - verify my techniques, etc.  If the result wasn't sufficient (i.e. my volume estimates weren't accurate enough), I would move up to HD.

Answer (score 0):

If the links were of the same general shape, could you create a base model in Solidworks?  Then you could take 2 pictures, and side view and a top view.  You would then need a way to judge the scale of the link in the picture.  Then you could just drive the dimensions in Solidworks such as length, width, radius, etc.